# jQuery Tags Manager – page is going to be reloaded with get variable

Tags: jquery-plugins

I've tried to implement the jQuery Tags Manager (http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager) the last days in vain...

What the environment looks like:
it is a bootstrap powered website with several elements on it which should be able to be tagged (within a bootstrap modal).

What I have done so far:
I have added the tagManager class to my input field.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="tags_0" placeholder="Tags" class="tagManager">
</form>
```

Furthermore, in the head section of my website I have included a custom javascript file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

The file looks like this:

```
jQuery(".tagManager").tagsManager();
```

Of course also the jQuery lib and the bootstrap & TagsManager css files were included.

However when ever I am entering a tag it does reload the website with the get-variable "?tags_0=test"

I am kind of frustrated right now. It seems so simple, but I cannot get it working...

Best regards,
Nico

Answer (score 0):

This probabily isn't going to help the original poster since this was asked some time ago, but I was having the exact same problem and when I searched for help I found this question, so my answer might help someone that ends up here with the same problem.

I was trying to use this jQuery plugin as well and I was having a hard time to get it working too. Spent hours checking the code and searching for help but always got to the conclusion that the code was correct, so I had no idea what was wrong. However, somehow, it then started working.
One thing I noticed was that if I had the call for the css file first and then the js files, it would show some weird thing in the place where it should have the "x" for deleting the tag. But if I called the js files first and then the css file, it would work perfectly.

This is the code I used:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-tagmanager.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap-tagmanager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="products" placeholder="Add your Products" class="tagManager">

<script>
 jQuery(".tagManager").tagsManager();
</script>

</body>
```

Hope this helps someone.